# ADO.NET recurring results from relationships

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, relationships

I'm working on a project in ASP.NET MVC 5, with ADO.NET EF to generate data from the SQL server. I have several one-to-many relationships in the database. When I fetch data and project it to a local variable, e.g. `var query = model.listFromDbChildTable.ToList();` where `model.listFromDbChildTable` is just entities loaded from the db. This is the lowest table in the relationship hierarchy.

So the thing is, and I am not sure why, every time I go to "locals" in VS, in debug mode, I can go deeper and deeper into my relations, for example, I am looking at a child table (department), and when I go to this child in locals, I see child has a relation with parent (above it), s I go to parent table, (I believe this is normal,) but when I'm at parent (table), again I can go to child table from there, and I am not going up one step back in the hierarchy, but so to say deeper, like a stair down all the time. So I go again to child, and child can go to parent again, every time with the same element. And I can redo this process many times?

So what is going on? Are my relations wrong or is this some normal procedure with locals in VS?

Answer (score 0):

The following image shows two tables that participate in one-to-many relationship. The Course table is the dependent table because it contains the DepartmentID column that links it to the Department table.

Basically any link between two entities can be explored(Table in SQL ,class in EF)
In SQL you refer just a column in child table as key whereas in entity a property  is create which has type of a class .
Like in below example, Course will have property name "Department" of type "Department" class as it depends on it (also a DepartmentId property).
you can read more in detail here on msdn..and Don't worry moving from SQL to Entity framework does give you small suprises :) .Hope it helps.

[Parent Child Entity MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

[image]